# CE 1.7: Merge two different databases in 1

Tags: magento-1.7, product, database

Well Hello,

I've the need to merge 2 different databases together. But! I need to keep some data from 1 and other data from the other one...

```
DB 1: is a multisite setup 
DB 2: is only 1 website... 

DB 1: has all the setups for the other sites plus it works with new layout 
and has some dummy products... 
DB 2: it's the db of the current life site.. but I only need the products,
users & their data and newsletters mails
```

-

**So my question is, do you guys know a way I could merge the 2 databases and have them working?!**

Comment: You're probably best off exporting and importing instead of merging databases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is not an *easy* way per-se to simply merge the data in the two databases, it's simply not the nature of MySql, and the large relational schemas which Magento uses means it wouldn't be as simple as copying data from certain tables into the other database.

The best (and really the only) option you have will be to export your data and then use the same tool to import the data into the other website setup.

My tooling suggestion would be to use [uRapidFlow Pro](http://www.unirgy.com/products/urapidflow/) for product information and the built-in Dataflow Profiles for handling customers.

Comment: I would upvote RapidFlow 5 times if possible. Unirgy makes some incredible products.  I think RapidFlow even handles order import.

Comment: so you suggesting me to export/import? I read this other question [here](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/3944/moving-products-from-1-4-to-1-7-dilemma?rq=1) that is kinda similar... they said it's better doing it with databases.

Comment: Yes, export/import is what I'm suggesting. In the case of the question you linked to, the poster was upgrading a single Magento installation to a newer version vs your case where you want to combine two instances of Magento into one.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is cart2cart, but the cost depends on what you want to move and how many records you have. In my experience, I've found it much more time consuming to move product and customers than to change setting to support your theme, but that's just me. Since db1 has more stores, if your going to keep them, just import the db2 over to replace/overwrite that data in that one store. You can overwrite single tables; you don't have to move the whole database.
At the end of the day, pay somebody to do this or buy a service. If it's you're first time, this process will really make you hate Magento.